# how to write ,correct registration query?

Tags: go

I am new on Golang gin framework.I have one problem.I want to write registration controller but I am getting error ,when I try to create user in database.I want to note that there is no problem on running.When I try to create new user with json request,it redirects me to "rows error" .If I have to add extra information,please note it

model/user.go

```
package model

type User struct {
    ID int
    firstname string
    lastname string
    Username string
    password string
    Isadmin bool


}
```

```
package controller

import (
    "LoginRegister/dto"
    "LoginRegister/repository"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)


type RegisterController struct {

}

func (lc *RegisterController) Register(c *gin.Context) {

    var registerRequest dto.RegisterRequest
    // var user model.User

    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&registerRequest); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "message": "Bad Request1 !",
        })
        return
    }

    db := repository.Database
    //if db == nil {
    //  log.Fatal("Database is null1")
    //}

    rows,err := db.Prepare(fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO users(`ID`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`Username`,`password`,`isadmin`) VALUES ('?','?','?','?','?','?')", registerRequest.ID, registerRequest.Firstname, registerRequest.Lastname, registerRequest.Username, registerRequest.Password, registerRequest.Isadmin))
    //rows, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO users(ID, firstname, lastname, Username, password, isadmin) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ;")
    //rows,err := db.Prepare(fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO users(`ID`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`Username`,`password`,`isadmin`) VALUES ('?','?','?','?','?')", registerRequest.ID, registerRequest.Firstname, registerRequest.Lastname, registerRequest.Username, registerRequest.Password))


    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("rows error")
    }

    //fmt.Println(rows)

    if rows !=nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{

            "message": "Successfully registered",
        })
    }





}
```

Comment: You're ignoring error, try to log it `log.Fatalf("rows error: %s", err)`

Comment: @Зелёный Thank you,After adding your column,I troubleshooted problem!